# unable to write to a file from within a excel dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, excel, dll

I developed a Excel dll which has the code given below:

```
 FILE *outf
 if((outf = fopen("filename.txt","w+"))!=NULL)
 {
   fprintf(outf,"hello");
  } 
 fclose.(outf);
```

Essentially I am trying to write to a file from within dll, the program executes correctly without any error but I do not see any file with "filename.txt". It is not getting created, I am in windows developing in c++ visual studio 2010.

Comment: which folders have you checked? it will create the file in the current directory for the Excel process.

Comment: You may not have permissions to write to the current directory. Try a path to a location you do know you have permissions for.

Answer (score 0):

It created the file in the directory where your Excel DLL (or XLL) is located since that is the current working directory for your DLL's context. Unless you moved your DLL this is the Debug directory under the project directory.

The Windows API function below can be used to retrieve your DLL's full path.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetModuleFileName( HMODULE hModule, LPTSTR  lpFilename, DWORD  nSize  );
```